# Upload and fetch images using Node and Express server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, backend

I'm building a website where users can upload images 
as a information to server and the admin responds accordingly.
Which tools/modules I need to use and what's the overall process if
I'm using Node js with express at backend. The database I'm thinking to use is MySQL but can also go with MongoDB if the overall
process is simpler and efficient there.

Comment: This is far too broad and contains requests for recommendations, which are off topic here. Please take the [tour] and see the [help].

Comment: This is not what SO is for. Please do the initial work and come back after you have narrowed down your problem.

Comment: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-set-up-simple-image-upload-with-node-and-aws-s3-84e609248792.
this will give you a basic idea. You can use s3 for storing images and in application level I mean DB just store the URL of the images.